# Google protobuf - cannot decode message

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I have 2 protobuf messages that I am unable to decode unless I remove some bytes from the beginning and/or from the end.

First message in base64 is:

**RQAAAPEmCgV0ZXN0MRAXGbj4KzKrldhBIAFCAQBKAQBRAAEAsPC/WQAAAAAAAPC/**

which translates to this byte array:

**45 00 00 00 f1 26 0a 05 74 65 73 74 31 10 17 19 b8 f8 2b 32 ab 95 d8 41 20 01 42 01 00 4a 01 00 51 00 01 00 b0 f0 bf 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 bf**

If I call Google's protobuf `Parser.ParseFrom(<above byte array>)` it fails with the exception **"Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type."**

But if I skip the first 6 bytes and the last 7 (so basically **0a 05 74 65 73 74 31 10 17 19 b8 f8 2b 32 ab 95 d8 41 20 01 42 01 00 4a 01 00 51 00 01 00 b0 f0 bf 59 00**) then it works.

Alternatively, if I call `Parser.ParseDelimitedFrom(<stream of the complete byte array>)` again, same story, unless I remove 4 bytes (not 6) this time from the beginning and 7 from the end (**f1 26 0a 05 74 65 73 74 31 10 17 19 b8 f8 2b 32 ab 95 d8 41 20 01 42 01 00 4a 01 00 51 00 01 00 b0 f0 bf 59 00**)

The second message is:

**RgAAAPA3CgV0ZXN0MhAmGdimrTmrldhBIAFCAQBKAgABUfYOIizeJGRAWYxpKU8HvFFA**

or

**46 00 00 00 f0 37 0a 05 74 65 73 74 32 10 26 19 d8 a6 ad 39 ab 95 d8 41 20 01 42 01 00 4a 02 00 01 51 f6 0e 22 2c de 24 64 40 59 8c 69 29 4f 07 bc 51 40**

which behaves the same as the first message except that for this one I don't need to remove any bytes from the end, only 6 and 4 from the beginning for `Parser.ParseFrom` and `Parser.ParseDelimitedFrom` respectively to work.

Can someone please explain to me what's going on?
Does it have something to do with **CodedInputStream**?

Answer (score 0):

The message has some framing applied around it. The protobuf standard does not specify framing, and in many cases (such as base64 strings) there is no strict need for any.

You should get specification of the framing from whoever wrote the other end of the communication.

There are some things we can infer:

- First 4 bytes are some kind of message index number. They don't match the message length, and seem to increase by small values.
- Next two bytes could be some kind of checksum. They don't match the message length either, so it is not a delimited message.
- No idea about why the first message has extra 7 bytes at the end and the other one does not.

But these are not enough to write a reliable parser.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! I just got a reply from the person who sent the payloads and apparently the message had to be decompressed using LZ4. There goes a couple of days of debugging...

Comment: @user3305815 Heh, funny how LZ4 preserves enough of the protobuf structure to be partially recognizable.

Comment: I know, right? completely confused me!